# Scala test unexpected error,')' expected but '}' found

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is my code to find maximum from list

```
object kp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()
  case List(x: Int) => x
  case x :: y :: rest => max( (if (x > y) x else y) :: rest )
} 

val a = 1 :: 4 :: 5 :: -4:: Nil
println(max(a))

}
}
```

When I want to test my codes in example folder with sbt

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/milenko/example/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/milenko/example/src/main/scala/example/ListsSuite.scala:138: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]   }
[error]   ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/src/main/scala/example/ListsSuite.scala:148: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]   }
[error]   ^
[error] two errors found
```

Errors refer to

```
  test("maximum with one negative number") {
    assert(max(List(1,4,5,-4)) === 5 )
  }
```

and

```
  test("maximum with some repeated elements"){
    assert(max(List(2,2,2,2)) === 2 )
  }
```

I do not have a clue why this happens.Here is the whole file

http://www.filedropper.com/listssuite

Now I have deleted some test from the file and it has only 135 lines.But I got the same

```
wc -l ListsSuite.scala 
135 ListsSuite.scala
milenko@milenko-desktop:~/example/src/test/scala/example$ cd ~/example
milenko@milenko-desktop:~/example$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/milenko/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/milenko/example/project
[info] Set current project to progfun1-example (in build file:/home/milenko/example/)
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/milenko/example/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/milenko/example/src/main/scala/example/ListsSuite.scala:138: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]   }
[error]   ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/src/main/scala/example/ListsSuite.scala:148: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]   }
[error]   ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 16/03/2017 13:43:43
```

Very strange, what do :138 and :148  indicate?

Comment: Look like a syntax error in ListsSuite.scala, probably before the reported positions. Could you add the complete file?

Comment: Give more details please. If you want, I have a little example to how check your function `max`. And little advice, you don't need to raise an exception, your function is not pure functionnal because there is a side effect.

Comment: it compiles and runs for me with sbt

Comment: @FatTail Can you try with the big file ListsSuite.scala?

Comment: @MotaF scalafiddle would be better

Comment: @alifirat Please take a look at my edit!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in the filedropper link (maybe it's expired?), but I know that one error that causes a similar compiler error is a trailing comma. I don't think this is your problem, but understanding what the compiler is doing could be helpful in your case.

Here it is in a simple file `Comma.scala`:

```
val map = Map(
  1 -> "one",
  2 -> "two", // <--- comma after last argument
)
```

Trying to compile this with scala 2.11 gives:

```
$ scala Comma.scala
Comma.scala:4: error: illegal start of simple expression
)
^
Comma.scala:4: error: ')' expected but eof found.
)
 ^
two errors found
```

The second error is like your one.

My guess is that:

- the `"illegal start of simple expression"` is because it's expecting an expression after the last comma (e.g. `3 -> "three"`) but it's encountering the closing bracket instead which it deems to not be a valid expression
- because the closing bracket got consumed earlier whilst parsing the arguments to `Map(..)`, when the compiler finishes processing the arguments it goes up one level to find the closing ')' for the `Map(`, but hits something else (in my case, end of file and in your case a `'}'` from an enclosing block of code. This yields the error `')' expected but ... found`

That second error matches your one so it could point to something going wrong where it's parsing your arguments and eating your closing bracket. The message itself is a red herring as it points to the closing bracket when the real problem could be earlier.

If you're a python developer who is used to trailing brackets this can lead to a lot of head scratching!

I had one case where the scala 2.12 compiler could actually handle the trailing comma, but unfortunately I can't reproduce it with a small example suitable for SO. This slight difference can unfortunately create non-backwards compatible code between 2.12 and previous versions.